# How to bundle node modules with native addons using webpack in node-webkit?

Tags: node.js, node-webkit, webpack

I'm trying to build [pty.js](https://github.com/chjj/pty.js) for use in [node-webkit](https://github.com/nwjs/nw.js) (i.e. nw.js) v0.8.6:

```bash
mkdir testapp && cd testapp
nvm use 0.10.36
npm install -g nw-gyp
npm install pty.js
cd node_modules/pty.js

# Build the native addon for node-webkit v0.8.6:
nw-gyp configure --target=0.8.6 && nw-gyp build
```

[The output ends with `gyp info ok`](https://gist.github.com/elliottsj/db8dbce929183b9443db).

With a simple *app.js* and *index.html*, the app launches with [no errors in the JavaScript console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itLk7.png):

```html
<!-- index.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
// app.js

var pty = require('pty.js');

var term = pty.spawn('bash', [], {
  name: 'xterm-color',
  cols: 80,
  rows: 30,
  cwd: process.env.HOME,
  env: process.env
});

term.on('data', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});

term.write('ls\r');
term.resize(100, 40);
term.write('ls /\r');

console.log(term.process);
```

*package.json*:

```json
{
    "name": "testapp",
    "main": "index.html"
}
```

---

I want to support ES6 and JSX compilation via [webpack](https://github.com/webpack/webpack) by bundling *app.js* into *bundle.js*:

```html
<!-- index.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Bundling *app.js*:

```bash
npm install -g webpack
webpack app.js bundle.js --target="node-webkit"  # This fails
```

But webpack fails with this error:

```bash
Hash: 6c3cd8b4ec249ab8fd05
Version: webpack 1.6.0
Time: 76ms
    Asset   Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
bundle.js  21244       0  [emitted]  main
   [0] ./app.js 311 {0} [built]
    + 10 hidden modules

ERROR in ./~/pty.js/build/Release/pty.node
Module parse failed: /Users/Spencer/Desktop/testapp/node_modules/pty.js/build/Release/pty.node Line 1: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./~/pty.js/lib/pty.js 10:10-46
```

Do I need to use a loader when `require`ing native binaries (like `pty.node`)? The [webpack documentation](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#target) says that the `"node-webkit"` target "supports native node.js modules"; perhaps it doesn't yet support native addons?

Comment: I don't have any experience with bundling to node-webkit, but you could give the [node-loader](https://github.com/webpack/node-loader) a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I wasn't able to get webpack working, I was able to get ES6 + JSX working by using [`require('babel/register')`](http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/require/):

```html
<!-- index.html -->

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Hello World!</title>
</head>
<body>
  <main></main>
  <script>
    require('babel/register');
    require('./js/app');
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
// ./js/app.js

import React from 'react';

React.render(
  <span>Hello World!</span>,
  document.querySelector('main')
);
```